# Does sys_brk return an address in 64-bit linux assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, system-calls

Supposing I run this code:

```
    mov     rdx, 0       
    mov     rax, 12     
    syscall
```

What is returned in `rax`? I guess it is an address pointing to a 4k page. Oh, and what is that `0` to `rdx`? Whatever value I gave it, `rax` ended up with the same number.
P.S
This is fasm code in Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Yes, it's an address. The argument goes into `rdi` not `rdx`. Should be the number of bytes you want. See also the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html)

Comment: I asked because when I read that man page, I saw this `int brk(void *addr);
       void *sbrk(intptr_t increment);` I saw that brk returns an int while sbrk returns a pointer to void. Could you explain why `int` becomes `address`?

Comment: Read the section of the man page titled _"C library/kernel differences"_

Comment: That explains it. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Just for the record, the `__NR_brk` system call you're using wants an address as the arg (in RDI), not a size.  Calling it with an invalid address like `0` or `-1` will get it to return the current break; that's what glibc does if you look at `strace /bin/ls` or something you'll see `brk(NULL)` and then `brk` with a new pointer a page or two higher.